# Is there any possibility to see logs of *.war file execution?

Tags: java, tomcat, heroku, webapp-runner

I started my web application using

```
java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port 9000 *.war
```

Is there any way to see logs now?

My console output:

```
sergei_rudenkov@EPAm18851:~/IdeaProjects/fsdf$ java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port 9000 web-archive-test.war
Adding Context  for web-archive-test.war
Feb 05, 2016 2:18:33 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-9000"]
Feb 05, 2016 2:18:33 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Feb 05, 2016 2:18:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Tomcat
Feb 05, 2016 2:18:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.24
Feb 05, 2016 2:18:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig getDefaultWebXmlFragment
INFO: No global web.xml found
Feb 05, 2016 2:18:33 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Feb 05, 2016 2:18:33 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-9000"]
```

My browser:

[image: browser]

I has `logging.file=mylog.log` in `application.properties` but it doesn't write anything.
I created war file using this command `jar cvf web-archive-test.war .`
What is interesting everything works fine when I launch it from Idea.

Comment: You are only using Tomcat in an indirect way. Check how https://github.com/jsimone/webapp-runner does handle logging. Which logging framework do you use ? Did you change it from the default ?

Comment: No, I didn't change nothing, I have a peace of log in my console but it's only about that tomcat has started successfully. Could I see somewhere logging of http request - responses. Should I do it grammatically inside my app save them to file and then recompile war file?

Comment: Show us the code where you log information. Perhaps you are logging on a DEBUG level and your loglevel is set to INFO (when you won't see any output until you change the level on either side)

Comment: Couple of questions:  *I have a peace of log in my console*  how you print the information in console? Also... which version of tomcat and OS are you using?

Comment: I am using Tomcat 8, Java 8, Spring Boot, and Ubuntu. To be correct I see only tomcat log, but I want to see my application log. My `application.properties` file looks like this: `logging.file=mylog.log` But it doesn't write anything during war execution it writes only when I launch it from IDE

Comment: post your logger config file, I think you're missing file appender declaration @Marged what you think?

Comment: To diagnose this you should add the actuator to your project, it will show you which endpoints get mapped. Similar info might be shown by running your program with --debug, but the actuator looks more nice and reveals more. Add `logging.level.root=trace` to your `application.properties` and see if the log still is empty ;-)

Comment: What I don't understand is why do use this webapp-runner. Spring Boot has other means to create a selfcontained application. Why not use this ? (Because your screen is missing the characteristic output if Spring Boot I think you are not using it the "standard" way)

Comment: Yes, this is not 'standard' way, I want my app to be deployed on heroku, and it can be run only using web-runner. Thanks for suggestions I will try them all

Comment: I asked webapp-runner developers on github https://github.com/jsimone/webapp-runner/issues/59

Comment: Please mention this from the beginning next time !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You implemented a logging system?

- **NO**: go to `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat x.x\logs` to find them
- **YES**

  You provided a specific log folder in config?

  - **YES** search for this folder location **in the server** filesystem.
  - **NO** search for the **default log folder** of your logging system.

Comment: I think the OP is using an embedded Tomcat

Comment: @Marged yes? Pitty I don't have experience with that... maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663192/logging-in-embedded-tomcat can help?